# jQuery dynamic dropdown box ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I currently have two dropdown boxes and a textbox.

I am using a database query to fill the first dropdown box and ajax to fill the second dropdown, depending on the value chosen in the first dropdown. I also am using ajax to fill in the input textbox once a selection from the second dropdown is chosen.

My problem is, with my current code, when I choose an option from the first dropdown, although it DOES fill in the second dropdown box with the data returned from ajax, I also want it to ajax the input box as well and return that value at the same time as the second dropdown value updates.

```
     $( "#manufacturerOpts" ).change(function(){
            val1 = $(this).attr("value");
            $.ajax({
               url: "inc/class/data.php",
               type: "POST", 
               data: "manu="+val1,
               cache: false,
               success: function (html1) {   

               $('#modelOpts').html(html1);

               val2 = $("#modelOpts option").attr("value");

              $.ajax({
               url: "inc/class/data.php",
               type: "POST", 
               data: "mod="+val2,
               cache: false,
               success: function (html2) {  
               $('#powerOpts').html(html2);    
               }
              });
                }
              });

    });

    $( "#modelOpts" ).change(function(){
            val1 = $(this).attr("value");
            $.ajax({
               url: "inc/class/data.php",
               type: "POST", 
               data: "mod="+val1,
               cache: false,
               success: function (html1) {  $('#powerOpts').attr("value",html1);  }
              });

            // $("#modelOpts").selectmenu('refresh', true);
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can modify your request to send the value for the textbox along with the dropdown menu options

```
$.ajax({
    url: "inc/class/data.php",
    type: "POST", 
    data: "manu="+val1,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#modelOpts').html(data.modelOpts);
        $('#powerOpts').html(data.powerOpts);    
    }
});
```

and in you server-side code you can easily find out the value of the first option for the `modelOpts` dropdown and send it as well

```
$data = array('modelOpts' => modelOptsHtml, 'powerOpts' => powerOptsHtml);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: You might also want to send `"mod="+val2` in the `data`

Comment: @Abhilash you don't have that value yet, also the data that is being retrieved has it.

Comment: Oh darn. I didn't read the code properly. I take back my comment.

Comment: I've tried to use your code but am getting a 'ReferenceError: json is not defined' error for 'dataType: json,'. Please advise. :)

Comment: Ah ok, i am no longer getting a json error now, but instead this is being printed into my select field: 'Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in C:\xampp\htdocs\dyn\inc\class\data.php on line 11'

This is what I am using for lines 10, 11 and 12: 
`
$menu = $model->getMod1($manu);  
  $data('modelOpts' => $menu, 'powerOpts' => $model->getPwrSpecific($menu));  
  echo json_encode($data);  
`

Sorry im new to stackoverflow im not sure how to format code in comments!

Comment: @Woddles the server side code was just to show how the data should be formatted to be sent to the client. It wouldn't work unless you supply  `modelOptsHtml` and `powerOptsHtml`, also there was another typo, see update.

Comment: @Musa i have it working some-what so far, currently now this is being displayed in my html: '<select id="modelOpts" name="modelOpts">A27/225</select>' which is the correct value, but I instead need the 'A27/225' value to be returned inside a option tag eg. <option value="A27/225">A27/225</option>  also the last problem is the value of Power is not being returned, i believe because when the A27/225 value is first returned as json, it escapes the value to A27\/225, thus performing the wrong db query and not returning any rows (i hope this makes sense) thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: @Woddles What were you echoing in your first version of `inc/class/data.php` for `modelOpts`

Comment: @Musa I was echoing the return value of my database query, which was returning something similar to this: '<option value="Model1">Model1</option><option value="Model2">Model2</option><option value="Model3">Model3</option>' etc, all in one variable so all that i was required to do for display purposes was to 'echo' the return value.

Comment: @Woddles the is what you should set `'modelOpts'` to in the $data array. Also use the value of the first option i.e. `Model1` to create the html for `powerOpts` and set `'powerOpts'` to it in the array.